# Solve the following Fredholm Integral Equation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, integral-equations

> Solve the Integral Equation :$$y(x)=\frac{6}{5}(1-4x)+\lambda\int_0^1(x\ln t-t\ln x)y(t)\,dt$$

Let , $$y(x)=\frac{6}{5}(1-4x)+\lambda xC_1-\lambda\ln x C_2$$where,

$$C_1=\int_0^1\ln t\left[\frac{6}{5}(1-4t)+\lambda C_1 t-\lambda C_2 \ln t\right]\,dt$$

My problem is on the integration $\int_0^1t\ln t\,dt$. The integral is improper at $t=0$ and the integral is **NOT** convergent....

How we solve the problem ??

Comment: this page could be of some help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_0 ^1 t \ln t \, dt 
= \frac{t^2}{2}(\ln t - \frac{1}{2}) \big|_{\alpha \to 0^+} ^{ 1 } 
= \frac{-1}{4} - \lim_{ \alpha \to 0^+} ( \frac{ \ln \alpha - \frac{1}{2} }{ 1 / (\alpha ^2 / 2) } ) .
$$ 
Note that the limit is indeterminate, as it goes to $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, and so we apply L'Hospital's rule to calculate
$$
\int_0 ^1 t \ln t \, dt 
= - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \lim_{ \alpha \to 0^+} \frac{ \frac{1}{\alpha} }{ -2 \alpha^{-3} } = - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \lim_{ \alpha \to 0^+} \alpha^2 = - \frac{1}{4}
.
$$

Comment: How it is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ ? It is of the form $\frac{-\infty}{\infty}$

Comment: The sign doesn't matter - it is about the size of the terms. Both the numerator and denominator are diverging "to infinity", that is, growing arbitrarily large as we take the limit. If the sign really matter to you, restrict $\alpha$ to be less than $\sqrt{e}$, and then the numerator is always $<0$, so factor a negative sign out of it and just like that now the limit is going to $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Though, the point is the sign doesn't doesn't matter to this aspect of the limit.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Hope that was helpful and cleared up any questions you had.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$I=\int t \log(t)\,dt$$ Integrate by parts using $u=\log(t)$, $v'=t\,dt$ which give $u'=\frac {dt}t$, $v=\frac{t^2}2$. So $$I=\int t \log(t)\,dt=\frac{1}{2} t^2 \log (t)-\frac{t^2}{4}$$ which does not make any problem even for $t=0$.

Comment: When $t=0$ then,  $\ln (t)=$ ?

Comment: $0.(-\infty)=$ ? Obviously $\not=0$, as it is **NOT** in extended real line $\mathbb R_{\infty}$

Comment: Please. $\ln$ is not properly defined at $0$ as a function on the real numbers - you have to take a limit to deal with the improper integral: $\lim_{t \to 0^+} \ln t \to - \infty$.

Comment: I also said it...Then how the integral is convergent ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 I posted some details about how to perform the limit calculation - intuitively, you should think that it converges to a value, as $t^2$ goes to 0 "faster" than $\ln$ diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: Just as izoec commented, $t^n$ goes faster to $0$ than $\log(t)$ if $n>0$